# Why is karma or Webstorm crashing when using nested describe statements in a jasmine unit test? Error: Cannot read property * of undefined?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, webstorm, karma-runner

I am using WebStorm combined with karma to run Jasmine javaScript unit tests.  **If I have nested `describe` statements then karma is crashing**, or maybe it's WebStorm crashing, I'm not sure.

The karma error output says:

> ERROR [karma]: [TypeError: Cannot read property 'should return a Foo'
>   of undefined]

- If I run the tests directly in Jasmine SpecRunner.html everything is fine and tests pass.
- If I remove nested `describe` statements then everything runs fine.

Versions:

- OS X: 10.9 (13A603)
- WebStorm: 7.0.2
- karma: 0.10.8
- karma-jasmine: 0.1.4
- jasmine.js: jasmine-1.3.1

What is causing it to crash?

**Code and test:**

```
var Foo = function Foo(name) {

    this.name = name;

};

Foo.prototype.bar = function bar() {

    return "Hello " + this.name;

};


describe("Foo", function () {


   describe("constructor", function () {


        it("should return a Foo", function () {

            var act,
                target;

            act = function () {
                target = new Foo("Gary");
            };

            expect(act).not.toThrow();

            expect(target).not.toBeNull();


        });


    });



   describe("bar", function () {

        it("should return a string like 'Hello' + name", function () {

            var target, actValue;

            target = new Foo("Gary");

            actValue = target.bar();

            expect(actValue).toBe("Hello Gary");


        });

    });


});
```

**Karma error output:**

```
/usr/local/bin/node /Applications/WebStorm.app/plugins/js-karma/js_reporter/karma-intellij/lib/intellijServer.js --karmaPackageDir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma --configFile=/Users/Gary/Documents/DotBox/test/karma.conf.js --coverageTempDir=/private/var/folders/5m/hfxftkwx5fsdnxf3g3nn5_2m0000gn/T/karma-intellij-coverage-4959093687844631591.tmp
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.8 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [Chrome 31.0.1650 (Mac OS X 10.9.0)]: Connected on socket vWDSeE6uTpA6RpuH05Bq
INFO [watcher]: Changed file "/Users/Gary/Documents/DotBox/test/fooSpec.js".
ERROR [karma]: [TypeError: Cannot read property 'should return a Foo' of undefined]
TypeError: Cannot read property 'should return a Foo' of undefined
    at createSpecNode (/Applications/WebStorm.app/plugins/js-karma/js_reporter/karma-intellij/lib/intellijReporter.js:51:37)
    at IntellijReporter.onSpecComplete (/Applications/WebStorm.app/plugins/js-karma/js_reporter/karma-intellij/lib/intellijReporter.js:190:20)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at onResult (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/lib/browser.js:177:13)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit [as $emit] (events.js:117:20)
    at SocketNamespace.handlePacket (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:335:22)
    at Manager.onClientMessage (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:488:38)
    at WebSocket.Transport.onMessage (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transport.js:387:20)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transports/websocket/hybi-16.js:39:10)
    at Parser.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at finish (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transports/websocket/hybi-16.js:288:16)
    at Parser.expectHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transports/websocket/hybi-16.js:299:15)
    at Parser.add (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transports/websocket/hybi-16.js:466:24)
    at Parser.expect (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transports/websocket/hybi-16.js:499:10)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transports/websocket/hybi-16.js:298:18)
    at Parser.add (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transports/websocket/hybi-16.js:466:24)
    at Parser.expect (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transports/websocket/hybi-16.js:499:10)
    at expectData (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transports/websocket/hybi-16.js:296:16)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transports/websocket/hybi-16.js:317:11)
    at Parser.add (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transports/websocket/hybi-16.js:466:24)
    at Parser.expect (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transports/websocket/hybi-16.js:499:10)
    at Parser.opcodeHandlers.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transports/websocket/hybi-16.js:316:14)
    at Parser.processPacket (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transports/websocket/hybi-16.js:533:8)
    at Parser.add (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transports/websocket/hybi-16.js:466:24)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transports/websocket/hybi-16.js:141:17)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:746:14)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:408:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:404:5)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:127:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:526:21)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**SpecRunner Output**

[image: SpecRunner Output]

Comment: Likely a bug in the setup or webstorm, I ran a similar kind of test in WebStorm with Mocha today.

Comment: yes it appears to be a bug in Webstorm.

Comment: This belongs on Programmers.se

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it is an issue in the 7.0.2 version of WebStorm, specifically the old Karma plugin.
The fix is to download the new karma plugin `version 131.560`.  Or when the next `version 7.0.3` of WebStorm comes out it may have the new plugin.

See some documentation here:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10010

and

https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-intellij/commit/589062a9500d889a8d328ff91cc185e6ec1fd127